# Trying to use Task.WhenAll with Task<string> not working

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to combine several resources in a single collection (s variable below). GetLocations2 returns a Task and I'm expecting to be able to add that to task results collection (again, the s variable). However, it's complaining that I can't add the task results to the collection because of the following error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Called

```
public static async Task<string> WebRequest2(Uri uri)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var result = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(result))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Caller

```
private static async Task GetLocations2()
{
    var s = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (var lob in _lobs)
    {
        var r = await Helper.WebRequest2(new Uri(lob));
  
        var x = Helper.DeserializeResponse<SLICS>(r);

        s.Add(r); //Getting red squiggly here
    }

    //var w = await Task.WhenAll();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to `await` before adding task to list, it basically unwraps `Task` created by `Helper.WebRequest2` (also it waits for `Task` to finish, so tasks in your original code will be executed sequentially):

```
private static async Task GetLocations2()
{
    var s = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (var lob in _lobs)
    {
        var r = Helper.WebRequest2(new Uri(lob));
  
        // var x = Helper.DeserializeResponse<SLICS>(r); this should be done after Task.WhenAll 
        // or using `ContinueWith`

        s.Add(r); 
    }

    var w = await Task.WhenAll(s);

}
```

Comment: But you're still awaiting it in your answer

Comment: @MindSwipe Thank you, stupid me, thought that I've deleted it)

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us sometimes, now it answers the question perfectly +1

Comment: @GuruStron, I didn't mean to edit your answer, I thought I was editing mine.

Comment: @Rod NP, was glad to help =)

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap both operations in an `async` lambda to avoid having to iterate twice:

```
private static async Task GetLocations2()
{
    IEnumerable<SLICS> w = await Task.WhenAll(_lobs.Select(async lob =>
    {
        var r = await Helper.WebRequest2(new Uri(lob));
        return Helper.DeserializeResponse<SLICS>(r);
    }));
}
```

Using `Select` will enumerate all the `Tasks` returned by the lambda expressions, then `Task.WhenAll` will wait for them all to complete, and unwrap the results.

Comment: Would ```_uri``` in ```new Uri(_uri)``` become ```new Uri(_)``` ?

Comment: @Rod You haven't shown where `_uri` is defined. I assumed it was a private field that doesn't change? Should it in fact be `lob` in your example? Naming the lambda's argument as `_` just indicates that it isn't used within the body. It's just a personal preference as it is similar to a discard.

Comment: Sorry about that I updated OP. You are correct, it should have been ```lob``` so I guess I can change that ```_``` to an actual variable, correct?

Comment: @Rod No problem; I've updated my answer accordingly.